# How to Reset video using html5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kind of new with programming in web and I'm trying to figure out how to reset the video after playing it for the first time. My code is:

```
var video = document.getElementById('home_video');
    video.addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.play();
},false);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `video.get(0).currentTime = 0` - not 100% sure about get(0) - may be jquery syntax there. I forget

Comment: Sounds like [loop](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp) could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use something like this:

```
var video = document.getElementById('home_video');
    video.addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.currentTime = 0
    video.play();
    },false);
```

Comment: it works on Chrome but not on Mozilla is there any settings when using different browsers?

Comment: I think there is a can play event that fires when it is ready to play. Something like this:
video.addEventListener("canplay",function() { video.currentTime = 0;});

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do it with video.currentTime = 0;

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp

Answer (score 1):

Add `video.load();`

Your Code after changes:

```
var video = document.getElementById('home_video');
  video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.load();
  video.play();
  },false);
```